# Shaded Jar Access

Tags: java, gradle

So I've done some research on shading jars and manage to do it successfully with Gradle:

```
configurations {
    shade
    compile.extendsFrom shade
}

dependencies {
    shade 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.11.2'
}

jar {
    configurations.shade.each { dep ->
        from(project.zipTree(dep)) {
            exclude 'META-INF', 'META-INF/**'
        }
    }
}
```

With a `srgExtra "PK: org/sqlite com/github/cossacksman/mrchunkl/repack/sqlite"` in earlier but shading isn't the issue as such. Do I access the packages shaded into the jar with the new or old package names seeing as they're shaded during the obfuscation stage?

Comment: do you need to shade for sure? you could package jars inside your jar with Capsule or when using Spring Boot

Comment: Creating a FatJar would likely be just as useful and I'll give it a go but for the interest of education this question would still be viable, right?

Comment: By the way I managed to package my file and use it successfully under the dependencies default package name `org.sqlite.JBDC` though for myself and others (since I couldn't find this information elsewhere), if you shade into a different package name it would be fair to answer this at some point